# Impossible to browse web after configuring iptables

Tags: iptables, firewall, internet, netfilter

I'm trying to configure iptables on my ubuntu computer. These are my rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp    dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp  dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftps-data
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftps

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp     dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Unfortunately, when I try to use the web explorer, it  can not connect. Just a blank page continuously trying to load.
I tried sending a ping to www.google.com, but the connection can not be established. 
Maybe should I leave more ports open?

[EDIT] I change the rules, these are my new ones:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state      NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Now it works!! :) I hope it is secure enough. I guess that block all traffic except the established connections by myself

Comment: You allow traffic *to* a http/https port, but not the return traffic.

Comment: Ca you, please, include the output of `iptables-save`?

Comment: The good news, your rules are ok, the bad, it looks like a network/routing problem... Your `INPUT` chain has 0 traffic. Can you `ping` your gateway?

Comment: Your third rule of `INPUT` chain accepts everything... It's like having no firewall 

Comment: i use -A INPUT -i io -j ACCEPT. Maybe the last line comes from that

Comment: yep, i remove the local traffic, and it disappear. But it is supposed that the local traffic should be allowed, if I m not wrong

Comment: Try accepting `ESTABLISHED` and `RELATED` and adding local loopback with `iptables -I INPUT 2 -i lo -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 1):

You're not letting any related connection in... Quick way to fix it...:

```
#iptables -I INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

P.S: sorry for posting in a rush, i'm in my way to work. I'll come back with details

Now, the details...

Every time you want to connect over TCP/IP, there's a "three way handshake". Let's say you want to connect to stackexchange.com (no firewall involved):

1. Your computer sends the first frame (SYN), something like "hey, i want to connect to you!". This frame leaves your computer from a random high **port** (let's say **47122**), through your `OUTPUT` chain, to stackexchange.com, port 80;
2. stackexchange.com replies with the second frame flagged ACK and SYN, something like "I've received your request, we can connect". This second frame leaves stackexchange.com **port 80**, goes through your `INPUT` chain, to your TCP **port 47122**;
3. Your computer replies with the third frame flagged ACK, something like "I've received your reply, I'll be sending data". This frame leaves your computer from the same **port 47122**, through your `OUTPUT` chain, to stackexchange.com, **port 80**.

The rest of the data will be sent through the created socket *yourcomputer:47122 - stackexchange.com:80*, going out through your `OUTPUT` chain and returning through `INPUT` chain.

Let's see how your firewall handles that connection:

1. First frame passes your `OUTPUT` chain freely, no rule to filter it, default policy `ACCEPT`;
2. Second frame is checked against each rule of your `INPUT` chain, does not matches any of them (you have rules to accept frames with `dpt` http, https...) and reaches the default policy `DROP`, and that's it... your connection attempt fails.

To fix that, in your `INPUT` chain, you either accept frames with source port 80 (not really safe...), or, considering `iptables` has connection tracking, you `ACCEPT` `ESTABLISHED` and `RELATED` connection (the rule I've posted above).

Also, I'll add some notes regarding your firewall:

- `INPUT` - you're accepting connections from any source to your `http,https,domain,ftps-data,ftps`. As long as you're not hosting the appropriate servers on this computer, I recommend removing this rules.
- `FORWARD` - again, you're accepting connections to be forwarded, by your computer, to a http server. As long as you're not sharing your internet connection or you're not hosting VMs, I recommend removing this rules.

Comment: I changed it, these are my new rules:

Comment: ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

     Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

     Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: But still having the same problem.....

Comment: Can you post the output of `iptables-save`?

Comment: # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Mar 26 15:26:16 2015
     *filter
      :INPUT DROP [0:0]
      :FORWARD DROP [0:0]
       :OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:76]
       -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
        COMMIT
        # Completed on Thu Mar 26 15:26:16 2015

Answer (score 0):

Petry pretty much nails it.

Basically, your setup permits traffic *to* a http/https/ftp port, but does not accept traffic coming *from* that port -- so your query goes out, but the response gets dropped.

Like most modern firewalls (defined as "after 1995 or thereabouts") the linux firewall tracks connections and allows for state-based filtering.

The line `iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` works as a catch-all -- any traffic whose initiation was permitted by any of the other rules in your firewall setup will be allowed to proceed without requiring any further explicit rules on your end.